# Continuous x no. of A and then after (n-x) no.s of B

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I am stuck in one of the problem related string in c++. My logic has worked well for some test cases, but not for all test cases. Please suggest me the actual logic of the following question::

I am given a string s of n character,  comprising only of A's and B's . I can choose any index i and change s(i) to either A or B.   Find the minimum no. Of changes that you must make to string S such that the resultant string is of format : AAAAA.....BBBBB.  In other words, your task is to determine minimum no. of changes such that string s has x no. of A's in the beginning,  followed by the remaining (n-x) no. of B's.

my code::

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    while (t--) {
        int n, i, flag = 0;
        cin >> n;
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        int cnt = 0, cnt1 = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str[i] == 'A') {
                cnt++;
            } else {
                cnt1++;
            }
        }
        int pp = 0;

        //cout << cnt << " " <<cnt1;
        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            if (str[i] == 'B') {
                pp++;
            }
        }

        for (i = cnt; i < n; i++) {

            if (str[i] == 'A' && str[i - 1] != 'A') {
                pp++;
            }
        }
        cout << pp << endl;

     }

 }
```

For example: AAB = 0 changes,  BABA= 2 changes , AABAA= 1 changes

How to approach this question. Do respond!!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212073/discussion-on-question-by-sukesh-continuous-x-no-of-a-and-then-after-n-x-no-s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following code to compute the number of changes needing to order a string containing unorderd A e B according to the order that shall be "A[...A]B[...B]". (function `countChanges`).

The algorithm (`countChanges`) used to count modifications acts in three steps:

- Step 1: counts how much 'A' chars are in the string (`cnt`).
- Step 2: scans how much 'B' chars are in the first `cnt` chars of the string increasing a counter (`sum`) for each encounterd 'B'.
- Step 3: scans how much 'A' chars are in the remaining chars of the string after the 2nd step increasing a counter (`sum`) for each encountered 'A'.

At the end of the function `sum` is the expected result.

The code also computes and executes the minimum number of swaps needing to obtain the string ordered according to the requirement.

The code contains two evaluation functions (the code under the `main`):

- `cntChanges`. It computes the needing number of changes (The code gives the result as `foreseen changes`).
- `executeSwaps`. It performs swaps on the string, counts them and may or may not show the steps performed.

Code result:

```
Do you have a code composed of A and B? [y]es/[n]o/[I] do it/[q]uit y
Insert your code? BABA
Do you want to print swap steps? [y]es/[n]o y

Input: BABA
Step 1 BABA swap(3,0) ==> AABB
Result AABB performed with 1 swap  - foreseen changes 2
```

--

```
Do you have a code composed of A and B? [y]es/[n]o/[I] do it/[q]uit n
How much codes do you want to generate? 5
What's your preferred length for all generated codes? 10
Do you want to print swap steps? [y]es/[n]o y

Input: AAAAABAABB
Step 1 AAAAABAABB swap(7,5) ==> AAAAAAABBB
Result AAAAAAABBB performed with 1 swap  - foreseen changes 2
--
Input: ABBABAAABA
Step 1 ABBABAAABA swap(9,1) ==> AABABAAABB
Step 2 AABABAAABB swap(7,2) ==> AAAABAABBB
Step 3 AAAABAABBB swap(6,4) ==> AAAAAABBBB
Result AAAAAABBBB performed with 3 swaps  - foreseen changes 6
--
Input: AAABBAABBB
Step 1 AAABBAABBB swap(6,3) ==> AAAABABBBB
Step 2 AAAABABBBB swap(5,4) ==> AAAAABBBBB
Result AAAAABBBBB performed with 2 swaps  - foreseen changes 4
--
Input: BABAABBABB
Step 1 BABAABBABB swap(7,0) ==> AABAABBBBB
Step 2 AABAABBBBB swap(4,2) ==> AAAABBBBBB
Result AAAABBBBBB performed with 2 swaps  - foreseen changes 4
--
Input: AAABAABAAA
Step 1 AAABAABAAA swap(9,3) ==> AAAAAABAAB
Step 2 AAAAAABAAB swap(8,6) ==> AAAAAAAABB
Result AAAAAAAABB performed with 2 swaps  - foreseen changes 4
```

--

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

unsigned int executeSwaps(string &x, bool printSteps);    
unsigned int cntChanges(const string& x);

unsigned int cntChangesJarod42(string const &x);
unsigned int cntChangesDamien(string const &x);

void questionToStart(int &c, size_t &cl, char &ync, char &ynps, string &x);
string generateCode(size_t n);

const char char1='A';
const char char2='B';

int main(void)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));

    int c;
    size_t cl;
    char ync='n';
    char ynps='n';
    string x;

    x.clear();

    do {
       questionToStart(c,cl,ync,ynps,x);
       if (ync == 'q')
            break;

       for(int i=0;i<c;i++) {
           unsigned int cnt=0;

           if (ync=='n') {
               x=generateCode(cl)
           }

           /* unsigned int fc2 = cntChangesJarod42(x);
           unsigned int fc1 = cntChangesDamien(x);*/

           unsigned int fc3 = cntChanges(x);

           cout << "Input: " << x << endl;
           cnt=executeSwaps(x, (ynps=='y')?1:0);
           cout << "Result " << x << " performed with "
                << ((cnt>0)?to_string(cnt):"no")
                << " swap"
                << ((cnt>1)?"s ":" ") << " - foreseen changes " << fc3 << endl << "--" << endl; 
           /*   << "foreseen changes (@Damien) " << fc1
                << " - foreseen changes (@Jarod42) " << fc2
                << endl << endl;*/
        }
    } while(ync != 'q');

    return 0;
}

unsigned int cntChanges(const string& x)
{
    const char * s;
    unsigned int cnt=0,sum=0,i;

    if (x.empty())
        return 0;

    s=x.c_str();i=0;
    // count char1
    while(*(s+i))
        if (*(s+i++) == char1)
            cnt++;

    /* verify how much elements, from start to cnt,
     *  are different than char1 (equal to char2).
     */
    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
        if (*(s+i)==char2)
            sum++;

    cnt=static_cast<unsigned int>(strlen(s));

    /* verify how much of the remaining elements
     *  are different than char2 (equal to char1).
     */
    for(;i<cnt;i++)
        if (*(s+i)==char1)
            sum++;

    return sum;
}

// @Jarod42
unsigned int cntChangesJarod42(const string& s)
{
    if (s.empty()) { return 0; }

    std::vector<std::size_t> switch_count(s.size());

    { // Count 'B' before index
        unsigned int sum = 0;
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for (auto c : s) {
            switch_count[i++] += sum;
            sum += c == 'B';
        }
    }
    { // Count 'A' after the index
        unsigned int sum = 0;
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for (auto c : std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend())) {
            switch_count[s.size() - 1 - i++] += sum;
            sum += c == 'A';
        }
    }

    return static_cast<unsigned int>(*std::min_element(switch_count.begin(), switch_count.end()));
}

// @Damien Algorithm
unsigned int cntChangesDamien (string const &x)
{
    size_t n = x.length();
    int cntCh_1 = 0, cntCh_2 = 0;

    // there's nothing to swap!! :p
    if (n < 2)
        return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (x.at(i) == char1) {
            cntCh_1++;
        } else {
            // x.at(i) is equal to char1

            cntCh_1 = min (cntCh_2, cntCh_1);
            // Now the foreseen swap are equal to cntCh1

            cntCh_2++;
        }
    }


    return static_cast<unsigned int>(std::min (cntCh_2, cntCh_1));
}

unsigned int executeSwaps(string &x, bool printSteps)
{
    unsigned int cnt =0;
    size_t apos=0;
    size_t bpos=0;

    // cout << "Start: " << x << " " << apos << " " << bpos << endl;
    do {
        apos=x.find_last_of(char1);
        if (apos == string::npos)
            break;

        bpos=x.find_first_of(char2);
        if (bpos == string::npos)
            break;

        if (apos>bpos) {
            ++cnt;
            if (printSteps) {
                cout << "Step " << cnt << " " << x << " swap(" << apos << "," << bpos <<") ==> ";
            }
            x.at(bpos)=char1;
            x.at(apos)=char2;

            if (printSteps)
                cout << x << endl;
        }
    } while(apos>bpos);

    return cnt;
}

string generateCode(size_t n)
{
    string x;

    x.clear();

    size_t i,cb=0;
    char ch;
    if (n==0) {
        n=rand()%10;
    }

    for (i=0;i<n-1;i++) {

        ch = ( char1 + (rand()&1) );
        if (ch == char2 )
            cb++;

        x +=ch;
    }

    if (cb==n-1) {
        ch=char1;
    } else if (cb==0) {
        ch=char2;
    } else {
        ch=( char1 + (rand()&1) );
    }
    x += ch;

    return x;
}


void questionToStart(int &c, size_t &cl, char &ync, char &ynps, string &x)
{
    int ex=1;

    do {
        ex=1;
        cout << "Do you have a code composed of "<<char1 << " and " << char2 <<"? [y]es/[n]o/[I] do it/[q]uit ";
        cin >> ync;

        switch(ync) {
        case 'n':
            cout << "How much codes do you want to generate? ";
            cin >> c;
            cout << "What's your preferred length for all generated codes? ";
            cin >> cl;
            break;

        case 'I':
            c=10; cl=(rand()&7)+9;
            cout << c <<" attempts with " << cl << " characters long strings will be executed" << endl;
            break;

        case 'y':
            c=1;
            cout << "Insert your code? ";
            cin >> x;
            cl = x.length();
            break;

        case 'q':
            break;

        default:
            ex=0;
        }
    } while(!ex);


    if ( ync != 'q' ) {
        if ( ync != 'I' ) {
            cout << "Do you want to print swap steps? [y]es/[n]o ";
            cin >> ynps;
        } else {
            ynps = 'y';
            ync = 'n';
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Damien, Hi, I used your function in my code, but I think that it contains an error (`cntSwaps` is a copy - I think - of your code).

Comment: Hi. For  "AABABAABBBBABA", it seems to me that the correct answer is 4. Note that I don't swap two elements, I count the number of times a element change value (A->B or B->A). I guess the difference comes from a different understanding of the problem. Did you check what answer Jarod's program is providing? I understand  that this programme provides same result as mine. I may be wrong of course

Comment: May be I misunderstood you reply! But it not seem always correct.

Comment: For you, what is the correct answer for  "AABABAABBBBABA" ? If it is 2, then clearly we don't have the same understanding of the question.  Note that for the OP, "BABA" corresponds to two changes

Comment: Yes, I understand that BABA is "ordered" with two change or 1 swap. But, at now, for me, it's still not clear why the number of change may result odd in your function.

Comment: Let us assume that the input is 3xB, 10xA, 4xB. Then the minimum number of changes is 3. So why are you chocked by a odd number of changes ? In some occasions, I guess your programme will not output the same sequence as mine

Comment: @Daniel, Yes I agree but I found 3 swaps then 6 changes! What am I wrong?

Comment: My output sequence is 13xA, 4xB, 3 changes. You cannot obtain this sequence by using swaps.

Comment: @Damien, If you refer to 3 x B, 10 x A, 4 x B you should obtain 10 x A and 7 x B .... or not!? That is the result my code obtains in 3 swaps.

Answer (score 0):

As state by Tfry,

you might count the number of switch needed to have

- XBBB
- AXBB
- AAXB
- AAAX

which is the number of 'B' before the index + number of 'A' after the index.

Then take the minimum:

```
std::size_t count_switch_for_ab(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s.empty()) { return 0; }

    std::vector<std::size_t> switch_count(s.size());

    { // Count 'B' before index
        int sum = 0;
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for (auto c : s) {
            switch_count[i++] += sum;
            sum += c == 'B';
        }
    }
    { // Count 'A' after the index
        int sum = 0;
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for (auto c : std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend())) {
            switch_count[s.size() - 1 - i++] += sum;
            sum += c == 'A';
        }
    }
    return *std::min_element(switch_count.begin(), switch_count.end());
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc06e5e1a93d0e9c).

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found in a simple loop, considering a 2-state process.

A state corresponds to the fact that for the given index, we *decide* to be in the A part or the B part. The transition from B state to A state is not allowed.

The corresponding number of changes up to index `i` can then be calculated iteratively.

For index `i`, let us call `countA[i]` the number of changes to get `A` only until index `i`, and let us call `countB[i]` the optimal number of changes up to `i`, assuming that somewhere before `i`, or at `i` time, we decided that the following part of the last string will containt `B` only.

It the current character `s[i]` is equal to `A`, then

```
countA[i] = countA[i-1]
countB[i] = countB[i-1] + 1
```

If the current character is `B`, then

```
countA[i] = countA[i-1] + 1
countB[i] = min (countB[i-1], countA[i-1])
```

if the last equation, `countB[i] = countB[i-1]` corresponds to the case that the transition to `B`  state already occurs, and 
`countB[i] = countA[i-1]` corresponds to the case that the transition occurs now.

In practice, we don't need an array to update `countA` and `countB`.

Here is the code:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>

int nb_changes (const std::string &s) {
    int n = s.size();
    if (n < 2) return 0;
    int countA = 0, countB = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (s[i] == 'A') {
            countB++;
        } else {
            countB = std::min (countA, countB);
            countA++;
        }
    }
    return std::min (countA, countB);
}

int main() {
    std::string s;

    s = "AAB";
    std::cout  << "number of changes for " << s << " is " << nb_changes(s) << "\n";
    s = "BABA";
    std::cout  << "number of changes for " << s << " is " << nb_changes(s) << "\n";
    s = "AABAA";
    std::cout  << "number of changes for " << s << " is " << nb_changes(s) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @Damien, Hi, I used your function in my code, but I think that it contains an error (cntSwaps is a copy - I think - of your code).  You may see it between the answer at the main post.